FATAL ERROR: Unable to parse input tree - device tree
I'm trying to parse my device tree to boot kontron sl28 module. For that, i try to parse the Device Tree Source: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/55027e689933ba2e64f3d245fb1ff185b3e7fc81/arch/arm64/boot/dts/freescale/fsl-ls1028a-kontron-sl28.dts
With this command:
dtc -O dtb -o u-boot.dtb fsl-ls1028a-kontron-sl28.dts


But get this Error:
Error: fsl-ls1028a-kontron-sl28.dts:37.15-16 syntax error
FATAL ERROR: Unable to parse input tree
Line 37 have following content:
44 IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_BOTH>; 
I can't explain what's wrong with the syntax and I suspect it has nothing to do with the syntax at all.
That's my first time trying to parse a device tree so please be kind if this is obsolete.

Does this answer your question? Device tree compiler not recognizes C syntax for include files

No, i get the same error. I get no errors when i preprocessing it with cpp -nostdinc -I include -I arch  -undef -x assembler-with-cpp fsl-ls1028a-kontron-sl28.dts fsl-ls1028a-kontron-sl28.dts.preprocessed but when i then try to parse it to the input tree dtc -I dts -O dtb -p 0x1000 fsl-ls1028a-kontron-sl28.dts.preprocessed -o fsl-ls1028a-kontron-sl28.dtb i get the same error as desribed above.

Note the cpp command above needs to be run from the top-level Linux kernel source directory (but you can change the pathname of the *.dts.preprocessed file to be outside the kernel source if necessary). When I tried it, I only got a few warnings from dtc about duplicate unit-addresses, but otherwise it compiled OK.

@Sarah04 "No, i get the same error. ..." - Then you need to inspect fsl-ls1028a-kontron-sl28.dts.preprocessed before you compile it with the dtc. Are there still untranslated macros in property assignments? FYI the dtc is a compiler, and not just a parser.

@IanAbbott You are right. I wasn't in the top-level linux kernel source directory. Thank you for your help!
